# any machine connection to local SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

I would like to hear from your advice. I am busy developing WPF Application using C# 4.5 and SQL Server 2012.

My App can extract any data from SQL database on my local machine. But I want to install my App into another machine that can extract any data from SQL database from my local machine. How does it work? I am not sure how to do this. Any suggestion?

Your advice much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the SQL Server network configuration guide? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189083.aspx  If the problem is client side, I always find http://www.connectionstrings.com/ helpful.

Comment: thanks for giving the links. they are useful to look at. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change connection string in YourApp.config.exe 
In my case it was something like this;

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: Cool thanks. What do you think is the best way to use mdf. file to make connection to database from C# or make connection to local Sql Server?

Comment: If you have one server where SQL Server is installed, Use it as remote server. To install sql server engine in all local machine is not good idea. Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: If i have one server where SQL Server is installed, do you mean i should create a server from Hyper-V on my local machine then I install sql server in this server. So i can connect database to remote server - do i understand correctly?

Comment: No, I mean you have 1 server in which you have installed sql server engine. And many computers(client-machine) can be connected to sql server which is in your server using my given connection string. No need to install sql server in local machines.

Comment: oh i got it. i will give a try. thanks so much! i am gonna mark answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change `ConnectionString`: `address_of_your_SQL_server` instead of `localhost` and don't forget to allow remote connections for your SQL Server.

Comment: how to get sql server ip address?

Comment: try to ask admin :) you something like address\instance, where address is IP or hostname of remote machine, and instance is name of insteance of SQL replication